# Mysql Query in Laravel active records

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

after a little bit search in stackoverflow I came up with this query which I wanted, and its like this:

```
SELECT * FROM workers where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_activity_time, NOW()) >= (60/per_hour*60)
```

each record is consist of these fields:

```
id   worker_name   last_activity_time   per_hour
```

so each worker has a per_hour field that will determined as actions number per hour.

last activity is the last time worker was doing an action.
It will get records that are qualified to run at current time.

so it will determine time interval with `60/per_hour` in seconds and selects the records which time passed from their `last_activity_time` till now is more than this calculated interval.

this works okay, But I want to know two things.

**1: is this query a good approach for this problem or its slow?**

**2: how can I do this query in `laravel 5.5` active records or query builder? and also it should return one record at a time.**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your query is fine because there were no joins and no subquerires just only condition is there. You can fire raw queries on laravel to -

```
$workers = DB::select('SELECT * FROM workers where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_activity_time, NOW()) >= (60/per_hour*60)');
// or you can make use of query builder as follows
$workers = DB::table('workers')->whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_activity_time, NOW()) >= (60/per_hour*60')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
\DB::table('workers')->whereRaw(...)->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

> 1: is this query a good approach for this problem or its slow?

It will depend on how many workers you have, you should try and see